# X, together with Y,

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I am currently studying for the GMAT and fell onto a sentence correction question:

The sentence is:

> The cat, together with my dog, ...*any verb*...

Should the verb be singular or plural?

> The cat, together with my dog, is ...

or

> The cat, together with my dog, are ...

The answer says it should be singular, but I don't get why it's not plural as it includes at least 2 subjects so plural

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
This is a general thing to keep the singular as explained in this link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/285250/142102

Comment: Turn the sentence around. Would you say that the cat IS feeding together with my dog? Or the cat ARE feeding together with my dog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are these two agreements all right?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/are-these-two-agreements-all-right) Also [The student, as well as x , … does it use a plural form?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/285249/the-student-as-well-as-x-does-it-use-a-plural-form) and perhaps others.

Comment: With *The cat **and** the dog are eating*, we always treat the subject as plural. With *The cat **together with** the dog is/are eating*, you might feasibly encounter both "pluralities" (I might make my choice depending on how "connected" the two animals are while feeding). But with *The cat **accompanied by** the dog is in the garden*, I don't think I could ever accept the plural verb.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, it make more sense now!